# How to work on same large file in different threads, not needing to update the large file

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a started and bound service that is operating on a bitmap. To start, I want my service to convert the bitmap to HSV. I want to do this in threads, as it will take a while for large images. I don't want to copy this bitmap to all of my threads( might as well tell you, the bitmap is converted to array of pixels using getPixels(...)) as the pixels array may be very large ( I am also hanging on to previous versions of the bitmap so space is definitely an issue).

I wanted to access the bitmap pixels in all of my threads.  thread1 would crank out hsv of the first X pixels, thread2 next X pixels...etc...  The threads are in their own class in their own file.

So something like this

```java
public class ImageProcessingService extends Service {

...
int[] bitmapPixels;

...
 public void createHSV(){
     ProcessingThread t1 = new ProcessingThread(1);
     ProcessingThread t2 = new ProcessingThread(2);
     t1.start();
     t2.start();
  }

 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {


        return binder;

  }
}
```

then in ProcessingThread

```java
public class ProcessingThread extends Thread{

private int mNumber;   

public ProcessingThread(int number){

      this.mNumber = number

}

@Override
public void run(){
   rgbToHSV();
}
private void rgbToHSV(){
  ImageProcessingService.this.bitmapPixels.length 
/* so this doesn't work to get the length because 
the thread is not part of the service class.(so if 
I can't even access the length, certainly can't access 
the actual array). 
*/
}
```

I could pass in the int[] of 
pixels to the constructor but I feel like that is 
making un-necessary copies (though I'm not sure).

I could also put the thread class inside the service class
but not sure about that.  and finally I guess I could make bitmapPixels
public.

Please advise on how to do this.  Thanks.  It would be enough just to show me how to access the bitmapPixels array

Comment: what you mean by "large images"? maybe you dont need those multiple threads at all and just one will be enough?

Comment: @pskink  the size may be a 4k photo or larger.  I already tried my algorithm on thumbnails in the main thread and there was a lag.  Besides, I need to know the answer to my question just for my knowledge.

Comment: You should not use the main thread but just one working thread

Comment: Why can't you pass the array as a param to the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could pass in the int[] of pixels to the constructor but I feel like that is making un-necessary copies (though I'm not sure).
>
> I could also put the thread class inside the service class but not sure about that. and finally I guess I could make bitmapPixels public.

You can do it any of these ways. Unless you find yourself calling `new int[]` a second time, or `Array.clone()`, you're only going to have 1 copy of the pixel array.

Java passes arrays to methods by value, but the value is a *reference* to an array; not the array itself. If you were to pass the array into the `ProcessingThread` constructor, you have not copied the array. When the different `ProcessingThreads` reference the array, they are referencing the same piece of memory.

It is safe for each of your threads to read from the array as they please. It is only when you start *writing* to a piece of shared memory, with different threads, that you have to start worrying about synchronization.